# Java thread program works in Eclipse, but not in terminal / command prompt

Tags: java, eclipse

This code runs fine within eclipse, but not in command prompt (or terminal). Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have no idea why it's not working. It runs all the way through in Eclipse, but hangs during execution in command prompt.

The Producer class generates random doubles and calls add(), while the Consumer class calls pop(); both call these 1,000,000 times.

Buffer.java

```
public class Buffer{

private double[] buf;
private int next = 0;
private int start = 0;
private int semaphore = 1;
private boolean isFull = false;
private boolean isEmpty = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Buffer pcbuf = new Buffer(1000);
    Thread prod = new Thread (new Producer(pcbuf));
    Thread cons = new Thread (new Consumer(pcbuf));
    prod.start();
    cons.start();
}

public Buffer(int size){
    buf = new double[size];
}

private synchronized void bwait(){
    while(semaphore <= 0){}
    semaphore--;
}

private void bnotify(){
    semaphore++;
}

public void add(double toAdd){
    boolean hasAdded = false;
    while(!hasAdded){
        if(!isFull){
            bwait();
            buf[next] = toAdd;
            next=(next+1)%buf.length;
            if(next == start){
                isFull = true;
            }
            isEmpty = false;
            hasAdded = true;
            bnotify();
        }
    }
}

public double pop(){
    boolean hasPopped = false;
    double toReturn = 0.0;
    while(!hasPopped){
        if(!isEmpty){
            bwait();
            toReturn = buf[start];
            start=(start+1)%buf.length;
            if(start == next){
                isEmpty = true;
            }
            isFull = false;
            hasPopped = true;
            bnotify();
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
}
```

Producer.java

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Random;

public class Producer extends Thread{

private Buffer b;
private double bufferValueCounter = 0.0;
private int numProduced = 0;

public Producer(Buffer b){
    this.b = b;
}

public void run() {
    Random r = new Random();
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
    while (numProduced < 1000000){
        double toAdd = r.nextDouble() * 100.0;
        b.add(toAdd);
        bufferValueCounter+=toAdd;
        numProduced++;
        if(numProduced%100000==0){
            System.out.println("Producer: Generated " + df.format(numProduced) + " items, Cumulative value of generated items = " + bufferValueCounter);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Producer: Finished generating 1,000,000 items");
}   
}
```

Consumer.java

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Consumer extends Thread{

private Buffer b;
private double bufferValueCounter = 0.0;
private int numConsumed = 0;

public Consumer(Buffer b){
    this.b = b;
}

public void run(){
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
    while(numConsumed < 1000000){
        double popped = b.pop();
        bufferValueCounter += popped;
        numConsumed++;
        if(numConsumed%100000==0){
            System.out.println("Consumer: Consumed  " + df.format(numConsumed) + " items, Cumulative value of consumed items  = " + bufferValueCounter);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Consumer: Finished consuming 1,000,000 items");
}
}
```

Comment: I have no idea either, because you haven't defined "not working."  Compilation error, runtime exception, logic error?

Comment: We could get out the magic 8-ball, but I doubt it will help much.

Comment: The program executes, but hangs in command prompt. It runs all the way through in Eclipse.

Comment: Honestly, you may want to go through the tutorials on java threading. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html  The fact that this code works in eclipse is not necessarily anything more than luck.

Comment: to clarify/rephrase what @Brian Roach said, the fact that this works anywhere is entirely luck.  you have used no valid thread synchronization mechanisms, so the behavior of your programs is entirely undefined.

Comment: Is bwait() not valid? The assignment's specifications are pretty limiting as to what I can use...

Comment: no, bwait is not valid.  please do some reading on threading and visibility of changes.  outside of any "thread synchronization actions", changes made by one thread are not required to be visible to any other thread.  so, the Producer and Consumer can each modify the "semaphore" value all they want and never see each other's changes (at least, that is one possible behavior).

Comment: so, I must be understanding this wrong. Both the Producer and Consumer are referencing the same Buffer object, which has a private int called semaphore. The only way to change the value of semaphore is to first access the synchronized function bwait(), and you have to do that in order to modify the Buffer further. What am I missing?

Comment: @Nathaniel - hmm, somehow i missed the use of synchronized on that method.  that is a start.  however, _all_ access to the shared state needs to be synchronized.  you're right, bnotify is not necessarily the problem (haven't checked all your logic).  the biggest problem is the lack of synchronization elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronized to pop and add methods. I think that should fix the issue.